# Шифрование файла логов в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, шифрование

Имеется файл, в который постоянно пишутся логи, возможен ли такой вариант, как шифрование входящих в него данных в режиме реального времени?

Comment: да, такой вариант возможен.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin хотелось бы узнать как, ну не прямую команду, а хотя бы ссылку на ресурс.

Comment: к примеру: дополняете код программы, генерируещей эти самые логи, соотвествующим кодом.

Comment: Кроме того вы можете разместить файлы логов на шифрованной файловой системе. Правда при чтении они будут автоматически расшифровываться.

Comment: Точный ответ будет зависеть от того, чем пишутся эти логи.

Comment: @nobody на сервере стоит logkeys, собранный из исходников, вот он и пишет, как я помню он С написан, данный язык я так скажем не знаю.

Comment: Наверное можно посмотреть в сторону `encfs` и `ecryptfs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если логгер не закрывает лог во время работы, то можно так:

```
mkfifo /tmp/log.log
logkeys --start --output /tmp/log.log
echo enter password:
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in /tmp/log.log -out /tmp/log.enc -pass stdin
```

В результате получится зашифрованный файл с паролем с клавиатуры

Comment: не выходит, можно ли как перехватить поток который идёт в файл и на лету его шифровать?

Comment: @ДмитрийТолкачев фифо какраз используется для перехвата вывода в файл. Возможно метод не подходит именно для этой программы

Comment: она просто не запускается когда указываю данный файл, решил написать свой логгер и туда встрою шифрование, благо есть библиотека)

Comment: надо будет попробовать